# Tankless water system not working after moving in

Tags: water, gas

We’ve just moved into a place where the gas has been turned off for 6 months.

The instant hot water service isn’t working. We’ve tried to use the gas oven, which didn’t work for a while until we ran it for long enough to get the air out of the system.

This doesn’t seem to be an option with the hot water which is at the end of the line.

At first the Bosch system was giving an F0 error, but now the oven works the system displays an EA (or ER) error

When a hot water tap is turned on the pilot clicker can be heard, but after stopping the clicker, the error comes up

Comment: Would find the make and model of the system, then go online to find the manual.  There is probably  set up instructions to follow to get it working again.  Check that all gas valves are open.

Comment: Contact your gas supplier. They may help you out. Last time I had gas, the company made a point of ensuring all pilots were lit and things all worked when they turned on the gas.

Comment: Yes, the gas company is supposed to send an expert to ASSURE all pilots are lit. The worst thing you can do is interrupt gas to a house (or a city) *and then turn the gas back on*.  Because then the pilots won't magically re-light, so gas will leak through the pilot orifices, slowly filling the house until it finds an ignition source. Then KABOOM.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  While that may be true for quite older boilers and other gas devices.   The OP stated he heard a clicking sound when he tried to get hot water.  While he called it a "pilot clicker" that was probably the wrong terminology, it most likely a spark igniter. And most gas boilers / tankless WH have a proving mechanism that closes the gas valve if there is no ignition.   But again, I don't totally disagree with you, we just don't know the age of the boiler, whether it has a standing pilot light, it is best to have a pro check things out after turned off for so long.

Comment: @George actually, my fairly new stove has the dumb kind of pilots. 3 of them too.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica REALLY?  So do you have to manually re-light them if you run out of gas or it gets cut off? Is there a proving mechanism that shuts off the pilots if they are not ignited?   (TEASING NOW): you horrible person, you are contributing to global warming with those WASTEFUL standing pilot lights, you should get a new stove that has electronic lighters, or get a fully electric stove that doesn't emit GH gasses (never mind that the power probably comes from coal or gas fired power plants). That would save you a few $ a year which would pay for the new stove in a century or 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will take a while to purge the lines of air.  For starters, I  assume you mean tankless water heater rather than instant hot, which is usually installed in the kitchen  with a very small tank.  Boilers and on demand (tankless) will try 3 times (that may vary) for ignition before it gives up and puts up an error code. All you can do is reset and keep trying until the air is purged and the boiler/on demand WH  gets gas.  There are other ways to purge a natural gas line, but I'm not going to mention it bc it's fairly dangerous and best left to pros. j

Lastly:  If you mean tankless WH rather than "instant hot" please **EDIT** your title to make it more clear.

Comment: Edited.  I’ll give it more of a go, thanks.